# Toggle 1 div on each click and close the previously opened div on another click

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a 2 sets of 4 `divs` each.
Now i want to achieve an effect like togglehead hav in `we we are section` try clicking on any of the employee photo it will open up a div and as soon as you click on another employees photo it will close the previous one and open up a newly click employees details div.

There are 2 set of 4 div in a row which will contain photos of the employees like `togglehead` have.
And on click i want to display detailed information in a separate div like `togglehead`

I want to achieve this result
[image]

Here is what i have tried, it is working but it is not giving effect like `togglehead` have.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click-box-open").on('click', function() {
    var $ans = $(this).next(".click-box");
    $ans.slideToggle();
    $(".click-box").not($ans).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.click-box {
  background: red;
  width: 100% !important;
  color: #000;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-30">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-box-open">
        <div class="team-container">
          <img src="images/product.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        </div>
        <h4 class="text-center text-black">MITCHELL KAPPOS</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center text-black">Designer</h5>
        <h6 class="text-center text-black">Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.</h6>
      </a>
      <div class="click-box mt-30">

        <h4 class="text-center">MITCHELL KAPPOS</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center">Designer</h5>
        <h6 class="text-center">
      Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga. Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.
     </h6>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-box-open">
        <div class="team-container">
          <img src="images/product1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        </div>
        <h4 class="text-center text-black">LEONARDO DA VINCI</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center text-black">Artist</h5>
        <h6 class="text-center text-black">Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.</h6>
      </a>
      <div class="click-box mt-30">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-close-btn">
          <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg text-white pull-right mr-30" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <h4 class="text-center">LEONARDO DA VINCI</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">Artist</h5>
              <h6 class="text-center">
         Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga. Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.
        </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-box-open">
        <div class="team-container">
          <img src="images/product2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        </div>
        <h4 class="text-center text-black">JOHN DOE</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center text-black">Project Manager</h5>
        <h6 class="text-center text-black">Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.</h6>
      </a>
      <div class="click-box mt-30">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-close-btn">
          <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg text-white pull-right mr-30" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <h4 class="text-center">JOHN DOE</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">Project Manager</h5>
              <h6 class="text-center">
         Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga. Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.
        </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-box-open">
        <div class="team-container">
          <img src="images/product4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        </div>
        <h4 class="text-center text-black">JOHN DOE</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center text-black">Project Manager</h5>
        <h6 class="text-center text-black">Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.</h6>
      </a>
      <div class="click-box mt-30">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-close-btn">
          <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg text-white pull-right mr-30" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <h4 class="text-center">JOHN DOE</h4>
              <h5 class="text-center">Project Manager</h5>
              <h6 class="text-center">
         Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga. Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.Similique sunt culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi dolorum fuga.
        </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
I have tried removing `position:fixed;` and adding `position:absolute;`
But not no luck.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/soeb/pLx7z7qz/)

Comment: is my answer solve the problem? hello?

Comment: Not exactly.!
Please refer the image i have updated in the question.
And here id the demo [link](https://jsfiddle.net/soeb/pLx7z7qz/)

Comment: i will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

To separate the div, you need to change the click-box css

take a **note***

**position fixed act almost the same like absolute.**

```
.click-box {
position:relative;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/4nmm0joL/)